# Converting EXECUTE Statements from Azure SQL to Snowflake

Tags: javascript, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to convert the below Azure SQL stored procedure to Snowflake. But I couldn't find an alternative for the **EXEC** statement yet:

```
CREATE PROC SAMPLE_PROC
AS  
BEGIN  
 DECLARE @BusinessUnitKey INT=(SELECT BusinessUnitKey FROM BusinessUnit WHERE BusinessUnitName='ABC')  ;
 DECLARE @LoadDate DATETIME=  (SELECT Cast(GETUTCDATE() as Date))  ;
 DECLARE @DataLoadLogKey INT = (  
   SELECT MAX(DataLoadLogKey)  
   FROM DataLoadLog  
   WHERE BusinessUnitKey = @BusinessUnitKey  
   )  
  ,@TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'ProductType'  
  ,@StoredProcName VARCHAR(100) = (object_name(@@procid))  
  ,@StarDateTime DATETIME = @LoadDate  
  ,@EndDateTime DATETIME = NULL  
  ,@Status VARCHAR(100) = 'In Progress'  
  ,@LoadDescription VARCHAR(1000) = 'Loading Data'  ;
  
 EXEC dbo.usp_procedure @DataLoadLogKey = @DataLoadLogKey  
  ,@TableName = @TableName  
  ,@StoredProcName = @StoredProcName  
  ,@StarDateTime = @StarDateTime  
  ,@EndDateTime = NULL  
  ,@Status = @Status  
  ,@LoadDescription = @LoadDescription ; 
END;
```

Could anyone provide the corresponding execute statement in Snowflake?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Snowflake stored procedures are written in JavaScript @Cerbrus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Working with Stored Procedures](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html) in documentation.

This is a rough stub that should compile.
I cant test the code, as I dont have ddl for your tables or data to validate, but this should give you a good start.

Best Regards.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_PROC()
returns VARCHAR not null
language javascript
as 
$$


var businessUnitKey , loadDate, dataLoadLogKey, sql,  statement, rs, message ;

message= "FAILED";

// get business unit key
sql = `SELECT BusinessUnitKey FROM BusinessUnit WHERE BusinessUnitName='ABC'`;
statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql});
result_set = statement.execute();

while (result_set.next())  {
    businessUnitKey = result_set.getColumnValue(1);
}
// get load date 
sql = `SELECT Cast(SYSDATE() as Date)`;
statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql});
result_set = statement.execute();
while (result_set.next())  {
loadDate = result_set.getColumnValue(1);
}

//return loadDate
sql = `SELECT MAX(DataLoadLogKey)  
   FROM DataLoadLog  
   WHERE BusinessUnitKey = ` + businessUnitKey + `;` 
statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql});
result_set = statement.execute();
while (result_set.next())  {
dataLoadLogKey = result_set.getColumnValue(1);
}


var TableName       = 'ProductType'  
  ,StoredProcName   = 'SAMPLE_PROC()'
  ,StarDateTime     = LoadDate  
  ,EndDateTime      = NULL  
  ,Status           = 'In Progress'  
  ,LoadDescription  = 'Loading Data'  ;


sql = `CALL dbo.usp_procedure(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7); `
statement = snowflake.createStatement({
        sqlText: sql,
        binds: [dataLoadLogKey,TableName,StoredProcName,StarDateTime,EndDateTime,Status,LoadDescription]
    });

message= "SUCCESSFUL";
return message;

$$;

call SAMPLE_PROC();
```

[image: How to call Snowflake Stored Procedures]

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake stored procedures are written in JavaScript, which can execute SQL statements by calling a JavaScript API. This API is similar to, but not identical to, the APIs in Snowflake connectors and drivers (Node.js, JDBC, Python, etc.).

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#implementation-and-api

You would be able to find a couple of code examples:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#examples